# Angular.js: Set form fields "dirty" upon submission

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

How can I make a form input to become dirty as the form is submitted?

This is needed so that the input fields with an $error can be

Example:

```
    name: <input    type="text"
                    ng-model="user.name" 
                    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                    name="uName"
                    required /><br/>
```

As the form is submitted, I want this field - if left blank - to be rendered using the "invalid & dirty" style:

```
    .css-form input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {

        background-color: #FA787E;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't allow submission if the field is required.  You should disable the submission button if the form is not dirty or has errors.

Comment: Hi @m.e.conroy, wouldn't that confuse the user to have a disabled submission button and no way to highlight the erroneous fields?

Comment: yes of course.  You should highlight the fields in error.  Take a look at **ngMessages** if you're using Angular 1.3, its a separate module that you'll need to include in order to use it.  Or, I added some code to my answer to show how you might do it the *old* way.

Comment: The problem with doing it upon submission is that you'd have to stop the submission event from proceeding, if you disable the submission button until the form is valid you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @m.e.conroy, thanks for adding details to your answer. It helped me solving my need :-)

Comment: Your welcome, glad I could help you solve something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the submission button until form is dirty and the form items are valid.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myFrmName.$invalid || !myFrmName.$dirty">Submit Form</button>
```

Using `ng-disabled` will disable the form submission button while the form is *$invalid* or the form has yet to be touched (not *$dirty*).

**EDIT**

I usually do something like this to display an error next to the required field:

```
<input type="text" name="myField" required ng-class="{true : 'has-error'}[hasError(myFrmName.myField.$error.required,myFrmName.myField.$dirty)]>
<span ng-if="hasError(myFrmName.myField.$error.required,myFrmName.myField.$dirty)">Required!</span>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.hasError = function(e,d){ // e = $error, d = $dirty
    if(angular.isDefined(e))
        return e && d;

    return false;
} // end hasError
```

**Example with ngMessages (Angular 1.3)**

```
<input type="text" name="myField ng-model="fields.myField" ng-class="{true : 'has-error'}[hasError(myFrmName.myField.$error.required,myFrmName.myField.$dirty)] required>
<ng-messages for="myFrmName.myField.$error" ng-if="myFrmName.myField.$dirty">
    <ng-message when="required" class="text-danger">The field is required!</ng-message>
</ng-messages>
```

The great thing about *ngMessages* is that all you need to do is add more `<ng-message>` tags for each type of validation for the field and just change the `when` attribute approrpriately.

```
<ng-message when="minlength">Your entry is too short.</ng-message>
```

Angular will display the correct message based upon whether or not the *when* is in the *$error* object for the field.

Comment: Hmm, indeed. Using that $dirty validation would allow displaying a message to invite the user to validate the fields. Good!

Comment: I was just going to add, how you might display a message next to the offending fields, its a bit different from AngularJS 1.2 to 1.3 as there is a new module in 1.3 called ngMessages that is a huge help in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$submitted` flag of the form to highlight the field if the form is submitted and is empty.

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="user.name" 
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
       name="uName"
       ng-class={'has-error': yourFormName.$submitted && !yourFormName.uName.$valid}
       required />
```

Or I guess just setting the form's dirty flag to true in your controller might do the same work. But I believe this implicitly changes the DOM as it adds a class to form which is not a good practice in angular.

> $scope.yourForm.$dirty = true;

Comment: interresting ng-class directive. Thanks for the help!

Comment: cubbuk is right, do not force your form to be `$dirty`

Answer (score 0):

in case you would like to do that programatically, there is a method named "$setDirty()" you could use for that purpose.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController